# My Visual- Code-Editor is not showing the included CSS in the Live preview

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, live-preview, file-link

I just reinstalled windows on my computer. The problem here is that when I was using the visual code editor before reinstalling windows with the live preview extension and it ran perfectly, but now after I installed windows the VC do not give me live preview like before.
It is just showing the HTML structure and not the linked CSS and Javascript files. There is no styling and formatting being shown on the page even though the page displays perfectly on the browser, tried everything but nothing worked. Note that both windows versions are the same no changes in them.[Only HTML shows up[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nr38J.png)

[no definitions found said by vs code editor also]

Comment: I dont it has anything to do with vscode or the extension. As i can see your background.jpeg is also not loading. Maybe your paths are wrong

Comment: paths are all right i checked them a hundred times , all the files were perfectly working in Dream Weaver and on browsers ,,i am so mush frustrated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it only shows the HTML preview without CSS. You have to use "Live Server" extension for that.

Download that from here:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer

GitHub Source:
https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server-plus-plus

Preview:

[image]

Comment: your answer worked vey well . Thanks to all the people who tried to help me..Thank You so much

Answer (score -1):

does a `.vs code` folder appear ? This problem happened to me once and by deleting the file everything went back to normal. IDK if it will work for you but it worked for me.

BTW there is a Youtube video on that topic, here it is  [a video for CSS files not working on live server](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U0_FKph6mZE&list=PLSabNJ3PEzP0CCLrukT5Yv56cjIdt0urF&index=12)

Comment: The .vs code folder is present on one of my partitions but not in the one where I installed the vs code editor.

Comment: Then you might want to check out the video

Comment: I watched the video but my code has only the names of the files not the paths,  and even if I make a new file and link another CSS file to it it still does not reads that  file and only inline CSS, or internal one is being read.

Comment: In order to copy the relative link of the css.style file into link href="css/styles.css"

Comment: i am doing everything but not working ,

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.live-server